# Comparing subsequent string elements in cell array in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array Data<1048536x1> of strings in MATLAB. I would like to compare adjacent string elements in the cell array. Is there a function in MATLAB? I tried using `strcmp` but it only works when you have two strings not for adjacent strings in a cell array. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare every string against the next string, use

```
sameIdx = find(strcmp(Data(1:end-1),Data(2:end)));
```

With this, the string at any position of `sameIdx` is the same as the string at position `sameIdx+1`. Note that this way, you don't need to check for the same previous string.